# Python Regular Expressions re.findall -- split a string into two

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I have strings like this:

"C BOS  - Traded from Royal Disappointments"

And I want to split them into everything before the dash, and everything after.  So simply in two variables, new1 and new2, I want the above to be:

new1 = "C BOS"

new2 = "Traded from Royal Disappointments"

I'm new to re so I can't figure out how to get the findall to work.  Here's what I attempted:

```
import re

myval = "C BOS  - Traded from Royal Disappointments"

new1 = re.findall( r'*\s\s\-',  myval )
new2 = re.findall( r'-\s*', myval)
```

I know it's probably not close but it's not clear to me how to make the expression.

Comment: Could you get away with `your_string.split(' - ')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.split`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "C BOS  - Traded from Royal Disappointments"
>>> re.split(r'\s*-\s*', s)
['C BOS', 'Traded from Royal Disappointments']
```

Assigning the result to variables:

```
>>> new1, new2 = re.split(r'\s*-\s*', s)
>>> new1
'C BOS'
>>> new2
'Traded from Royal Disappointments'
```

A **non-regex** version, but requires two passes:

```
>>> map(str.strip, s.split('-'))
['C BOS', 'Traded from Royal Disappointments']
```

If the string contains more than 1 `-` and you still want to split only once, then pass the split count to `re.split`:

```
>>> s = "C BOS  - Traded from Royal Disappointments  -  foobar"
>>> re.split(r'\s*-\s*', s, 1)
['C BOS', 'Traded from Royal Disappointments  -  foobar']
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this without re, as long as your string example holds true.

Things to watch out for: more then one `'-'` or no `'-'`

You may want to handle the possible exception for the split and assignment.

```
>>> example = "C BOS  - Traded from Royal Disappointments"
>>> before, after = example.split('-')
>>> before = before.strip()
>>> after = after.strip()
>>> print before
C BOS
>>> print after
Traded from Royal Disappointments
>>>
```